# Get array from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sapper

I have tried to get the array I can log inside the function to be used outside. I’m using sapper. Have been stuck with this for multiple hours now, so it was time to reach out to the community!

```js
let dvd = [];
let artistName = [];
let searchString = [];

onMount(async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`artists/all`);
    const data = await res.json();

    const newdata = data.map(x => {
        if (x.titles.length > 0) {
            dvd.push(x.titles[0].graphics.dvd)
            artistName.push(x.titles[0])
        }
    })
})

let searchTerm = '';
    
async function getData() {
    searchString.push(artistName.filter(d => d.artistName === searchTerm));
    console.log(searchString)
}
```

Comment: are you referring to the async function?

Comment: Yes, the async getdata.

Comment: var result=await getData()???

Comment: What is the HTML portion of this component? I'm not understanding how `getData` is being called, nor what exactly `searchString` is supposed to be. I think the largest part of your issue is that calling push on array will not trigger svelte'e recompile. you should reset the array with an equality statement such as `searchString = artistName.filter(...)`

Comment: When I do it like that, I get it actually more as I want it which is great. But I cant still get it outside the function. <input bind:value={searchTerm} placeholder="enter your name">
<button on:click|preventDefault={getData}>asd</button>
{searchString}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, your issue is that the updated value of `searchString` is not being applied to the DOM. This is due to how Svelte's reactivity works. From the [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects):

> Because Svelte's reactivity is triggered by assignments, using array methods like push and splice won't automatically cause updates.

You should update `getData` to assign to `searchString` instead of calling `push`.

```js
async function getData() {
    searchString = [...searchString, artistName.filter(d => d.artistName === searchTerm)];
    console.log(searchString)
}
```